# how to save full size photo on SD card in android

Tags: android, image

I am taking photo from camera and saving it on SD card. But saves image will be smaller than the actual picture. Can any one help me to store full size photo.I am using following code

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent1, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
        && null != data) {

    custId = cid.getText().toString();

    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    try {
        File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"photo.png");
        f1.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(f1);
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fs);
        fs.flush();
        fs.close();
        photoPath = f1.getAbsolutePath();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are half-right. Check out [Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) it is already given.